# gprof shows a simple signal handler takes a lot of CPU

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, signals, gprof

I use gprof to analysis a program running on linux which uses a 25ms interval timer (created by timer_create()) to update a global variable. The signal handler is something like update_every_25ms(), it calls profile_dummy() to increase a grobal variable:

```
static void update_every_25ms(int sig_nr) { profile_dummy(); }
void profile_dummy(void) { global_var++; }
```

The timer is created through:

```
timer_t timer;
struct itimerspec itimer;
timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, &timer)
itimer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
itimer.it_interval.tv_nsec = 25 * 1000 * 1000;
timer_settime(timer, 0, &itimer, NULL);
```

My program do a lot of heavy works but gprof shows that the update_every_25ms() functions takes the most of time when CPU usage is 100%, and this function itself takes about 1.53ms per call!

Following are several groups of the gprof output when the interval is 25ms:

```
%time  cumulative  self     calls  self    total    name
       seconds     seconds         ms/call ms/call
3.72   116.26      7.76     22963  0.34    0.34     profile_dummy
```

Here CPU usage is 60%.
Why does profile_dummy() need 0.34ms per call?

```
%time  cumulative  self     calls  self    total    name
       seconds     seconds         ms/call ms/call
9.38   38.87       38.87    25349  0.00    0.00     profile_dummy
```

Here CPU usage is 100%.
38.87s / 25349 = 1.53ms but gprof outputs 0.00, what happend?

```
%time  cumulative  self     calls  self    total    name
       seconds     seconds         ms/call ms/call
6.21   270.58      57.72 59105     0.00    0.00     profile_dummy
```

Here CPU usage is 90%.
And 57.72s / 59105 = 0.98ms but gprof outputs 0.00 too.

This one is the gprof output when I changed the timer interval to 25s:

```
%time  cumulative  self     calls  self    total    name
       seconds     seconds         ms/call ms/call
0.01   287.52      0.03  23        1.30    1.30     profile_dummy
```

The function just increase a global variable, why does it need 1.30ms?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Perhaps edit question to show the timer_create() call with the options you used

Comment: Thanks jwpat7. I added the timer code.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you did not quote the scalings (`us`, `ms`, etc ...) printed out by gprof as part of the column headers?

Comment: @alk Sorry, I can't copy the gprof output out but type the column headers and all other data by hand, so I just input the main part.

Comment: Hmm .. - I feel it would be interesting to know if we talked about milli, micro or nano seconds.

Comment: I added the time unit, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just hazarding a guess here.

`gprof` has a signal interrupt every 10ms, at which time it samples the program counter (PC).
The total self time of a routine is the number of samples landing in that routine.
Since it also counts calls to the routine, it can get the average self time per call.

Normally, when your program is blocked, like for I/O, sleep, or multitasking suspension, the PC is meaningless, so the interrupts are suspended.
That's why `gprof` cannot see I/O at all.

However, if you have your own timer interrupt, that may only mask the profiler interrupt, not suspend it, causing it to be answered after your timer interrupt is dismissed, which might put the PC preferentially in your interrupt handler.

But that's just a guess.

Unless this is purely an academic question, there are better profilers than `gprof`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to check if it is the reason you said? If I make no progress, I will try other profilers.

Comment: @Dustin: There are much better profilers than `gprof`, like [*oprofile*](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) and [*Zoom*](http://www.rotateright.com/), but personally, I'm not just interested in getting measurements. I want to make code go as fast as possible, and for me, [*the best profiler is **no** profiler.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)